# Can you create spreadsheet in gas & get ID & getActive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Multiple versions of the spreadsheet with the subset of data exist on my drive and I have a way to get the most recent but I thought that if I could capture the ID when I created it I would not have to run that extra code. If I just create  a spreadsheet the return is a 'spreadsheet' which I can `.getActiveSheet().getRange(. . . ).setValues(. . .)`
If I create and immediately getId then get use DriveApp.getFileById the return is a 'file'. It has a mime type of spreadsheet but cannot be used with .getActiveSheet() etc.  Why?  Is there a way to get the ID when creating a spreadsheet and still work with that new sheet?

```
function createSubset(fileName) {
//
//  var mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet';
  
  baseSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // "StudentRosterForPractice"
  baseSheet = baseSs.getSheetByName("Roster");
//                     there are formulas save below actual data but no in column B
  var totDataRows = cntDataRows (baseSheet.getRange('B1:B').getValues()) - 1;
  dataSubset = baseSheet.getRange(3, 2, totDataRows, 2).getValues();
  
//            ---- this does NOT work ----
//  tempSsId = SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName).getId();
//  tempSs = DriveApp.getFileById(tempSsId);  // returns file
//  Logger.log("tempSs.getMimeType(): " + tempSs.getMimeType() );
////     tempSs.getMimeType(): application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
//  tempSs.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, totDataRows, 2).setValues(dataSubset);
////     gets TypeError: tempSs.getActiveSheet is not a function
//  return tempSsId;
  
//            ---- this does work ----
  tempSs = SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName);  // return spreadhsheet
  tempSs.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, totDataRows, 2).setValues(dataSubset);
  return null;
  
}

/**
 * Number rows with actual data. There is a row of forumulas.
 */
function cntDataRows (colB)  {
  var count = 0 ;
  colB.forEach(
    function(item)  {
      if ( item != "" )  {           // no formula in last name column
        count = count + 1;
      }
    }
  ) ;
  Logger.log("totDataRows: " + count);
  return count
}

function testCreateSubset()    {
  var ssName = 'tempSs';  //subset name
  tempSsId = createSubset(ssName);
}
```

---

Thank you Marios.
My subset spreadsheet only has one sheet so that was not a problem. I am surprised that I can getActiveSheet on the subset even though the script is bound to the base spreadsheet.

There is still a problem however. When I create my subset, return the ID and create the PDF I get these messages

```
totDataRows: 41
Nov 8, 2020, 8:54:51 AM Info    spreadsheet ID: 1t16QOEqT2OP8vVmdTueT2hqQjTGdlMQLAc7XnJNWScM
Nov 8, 2020, 8:54:51 AM Info    In makeBlobPdf spreadsheet ID: 1t16QOEqT2OP8vVmdTueT2hqQjTGdlMQLAc7XnJNWScM
Nov 8, 2020, 8:54:51 AM Info    URL to be fetched: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t16QOEqT2OP8vVmdTueT2hqQjTGdlMQLAc7XnJNWScM/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=false&fitw=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&printnotes=false&pagenumbers=false&pagenum=CENTER&gridlines=false&fzr=true&top_margin=0.15&left_margin=0.15&right_margin=0.15&bottom_margin=0.15

 but the PDF is empty. If I open the subset and get the ID, hardcode it in the script and create the PDF  the messages are: 
In makeBlobPdf spreadsheet ID: 1t16QOEqT2OP8vVmdTueT2hqQjTGdlMQLAc7XnJNWScM
Nov 8, 2020, 8:57:28 AM Info    URL to be fetched: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t16QOEqT2OP8vVmdTueT2hqQjTGdlMQLAc7XnJNWScM/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=false&fitw=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&printnotes=false&pagenumbers=false&pagenum=CENTER&gridlines=false&fzr=true&top_margin=0.15&left_margin=0.15&right_margin=0.15&bottom_margin=0.15
```

The ID received in the make PDF code is the same and the URL generated is the same but the PDF where the ID was hardcoded has data and the PDF where it was passed from the create subset is empty. The create PDF code is unchanged.

Works:

```
  var ssName = 'tempSs';  //subset name
//  var spreadsheetId = createSubset(ssName);
//  Logger.log("spreadsheet ID: " + spreadsheetId );
  var spreadsheetId = "1t16QOEqT2OP8vVmdTueT2hqQjTGdlMQLAc7XnJNWScM";
  
  var blobPdf = makeBlobPdf(spreadsheetId, ssName);
```

Returns empty PDF:

```
  var ssName = 'tempSs';  //subset name
  var spreadsheetId = createSubset(ssName);
  Logger.log("spreadsheet ID: " + spreadsheetId );
//  var spreadsheetId = "1t16QOEqT2OP8vVmdTueT2hqQjTGdlMQLAc7XnJNWScM";
  
  var blobPdf = makeBlobPdf(spreadsheetId, ssName);
```

---

**Corrected createSubset**

```
function createSubset(fileName) {;
  
  baseSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // "StudentRosterForPractice"
  baseSheet = baseSs.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
//                     there are formulas saved below actual data but no in column B
  var totDataRows = cntDataRows (baseSheet.getRange('B1:B').getValues()) - 1;
  dataSubset = baseSheet.getRange(3, 2, totDataRows, 2).getValues();
  
  tempSsId = SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName).getId();
  tempSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempSsId);
  tempSs.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, totDataRows, 2).setValues(dataSubset);
  return tempSsId;
}
```

**Code that calls createSubset and makeBlobPdf**

```
function createAndMailPdf ()  {

  var ssName = 'tempSs';  //subset name
  var spreadsheetId = createSubset(ssName);
  Logger.log("spreadsheet ID: " + spreadsheetId );
//  var spreadsheetId = "1t16QOEqT2OP8vVmdTueT2hqQjTGdlMQLAc7XnJNWScM";
  
  var blobPdf = makeBlobPdf(spreadsheetId, ssName);
  
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)    {
    var emailAddress = "blah blah @ blah";
    var subject = "With useless PDF file";
    
    var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('letterBody').getContent();
    var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('letterBody');
    var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();
           
    MailApp.sendEmail(
    { to: emailAddress,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message,
      attachments: blobPdf}
    );
  }    else    {
    Logger.log("Mail quota exceeded but the PDF has been saved");
  }
}
```

**The makeBlobPdf code:**

```
function makeBlobPdf (spreadsheetId, ssName) {
  
  Logger.log("In makeBlobPdf spreadsheet ID: " + spreadsheetId );
  var marginStringValue = '0.15';
  var margin = '_margin=' + marginStringValue;
  var margins = '&top' + margin + '&left' + margin
  + '&right' + margin + '&bottom' + margin;
  
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'
    + spreadsheetId + '/export?'
    + 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
    + '&size=A4'
    + '&portrait=false'
    + '&fitw=true' // Fit to width
    + '&sheetnames=false'
    + '&printtitle=false'
    + '&printnotes=false'
    + '&pagenumbers=false'
    + '&pagenum=CENTER'
    + '&gridlines=false'
    + '&fzr=true' // Repeat frozen rows
    + margins;
  
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  
  Logger.log("URL to be fetched: " + url );
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });
  
  var attachName = ssName + '.pdf';
  var pdfBlob = result.getBlob().setName(attachName);
  
  return pdfBlob;
};
```

Comment: *this does NOT work*. Was there a error thrown?

Comment: The problem is the PDF is empty. No error is thrown.

Comment: Followup question should be posted as a new question rather than edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

The issue in your code is that there is no method `getActiveSheet()`
for a [file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file). It makes sense since a file can be anything in your
google drive. It wouldn't make sense to have a spreadsheet method like `getActiveSheet()` being applied to an image or a folder for example. As a result `tempSs.getActiveSheet()` is invalid since `tempSs` is a type of file in the deleted part of your code.

Here is the proper way to do that.

If you want to create the file and get its `ID` directly. And then you can use `openById` to get the spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
var fileName = 'testname';
var file = Drive.Files.insert({title: fileName, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}); // file 
var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.id); // Spreadsheet file
newFile.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, totDataRows, 2).setValues(dataSubset);
}
```

But keep in mind `newFile.getActiveSheet()` gives the first sheet in your file. You might want to use `newFile.getSheetByName('Sheet1')` instead.

To use this code please enable Drive API.

[image]

Comment: Why Drive Advanced Google service?

Comment: Marios, I like your solution but there is still a problem. I added to the original question as it would not fit in the comment.

Comment: What is ```createSubset``` ? One of your custom functions? Also please remember that if the nature of the question differs from the original one it should be asked in a new stack overflow question.

Comment: createSubset is in the original question. It takes some information from an existing spreadsheet and writes it to a new one. I wanted to get the ID of the new one so I could send it in as an email attachement. The ID that I get with the suggested code results in a blank PDF attachment but a hardcoded ID, acquired by opening the new spreadsheet, results in a good PDF attachment. The PDF attachment creation and the email logic are the same. The only difference is the ID obtained from the new spreadsheet.

Comment: @aNewb can you use my solution but instead use `newFile.getSheetByName('Sheet1')` where change `Sheet1` to the sheet name you want to get the pdf. If you tried this already, post exactly the code you are using because I am afraid that you have some return statements that block your code from executing correctly. Post the full code in your question.

Comment: Marios. I created a copy of my sheet and named it Sheet1. I am not sure what else you wanted me to try. I have included all the code.

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> Can you create spreadsheet in gas & get ID & getActive?

Yes. Bear in mind that running `getActiveSheet()` for the created spreadsheet will return the firts sheet.

Regarding `DriveApp.getFileById(id)` it returns a File object not a Spreadsheet object.

The **Class File** hasn't a `getActiveSheet()` method. If you wan to use this method one opction is to use `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` or `SpreadsheetApp.open(file)`

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you are encountering is that your sheet is being created but is taking some time to set the values in the function `createSubset()`. Therefore, while the creation of the Spreadsheet is complete, the values of the sheet have not been set yet which is done in the background.

This makes that `createSubset()` returns the Spreadsheet ID to the other functions and the PDF file is immediately created (but the cell values have not been set yet). This leads to your current behaviour where you are sending an empty Spreadsheets PDF because the cell values had not been set yet.

To force the cells to update with the right values and avoid sending the PDF before the Spreadsheet is all ready you can use the function [flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) which applies all the pending changes to the Spreadsheet. Use it as follows:

```js
function createSubset(fileName) {;
  
  baseSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // "StudentRosterForPractice"
  baseSheet = baseSs.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
//                     there are formulas saved below actual data but no in column B
  var totDataRows = cntDataRows (baseSheet.getRange('B1:B').getValues()) - 1;
  dataSubset = baseSheet.getRange(3, 2, totDataRows, 2).getValues();
  
  tempSsId = SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName).getId();
  tempSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempSsId);
  tempSs.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, totDataRows, 2).setValues(dataSubset);
  // FORCE ALL UPDATES IN THE SPREADSHEET BEFORE RETURNING THE SPREADHSEET ID
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return tempSsId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mateo. I can only check one answer is correct so I guess I should have split the problem. It seemed like a single problem to me. I did not know how to get the id and then the solution to get it did not work. Many thanks for stepping in.

Comment: Hi ! Did my answer solved your issue? If so remember that you can accept/upvote correct answers. Let me know if you still have any issues with your question :D

Comment: Yes Mateo = as you see in my previous comment,  I can only check one answer as correct. I guess I should have split the problem. I did not realize there were two problems. Your answer was critical to the total success. Thank you again for your prompt correct explanation.

Comment: Ah ok now I fully undestand what you mean. Yes, please next time ask separate questions specially if the follow up question is not related to the original question. As my answer solved part of your question please consider upvoting it. Thanks ! :D